# how to use GML as an input of WMS

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a GML file ,including 30000 points. It has 2 values(interpolated value and variance) assoiated with it. I want to display this GML file using web map services(WMS). How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? 
You can use Geoserver (http://geoserver.org/) to serve GML files as WMS or WFS or whatever you want. If you want to display the file then you could use OpenLayers or something similar.